# Maximum size of payload sent as POST request (Django)

Tags: django, python-requests

Say I have a Django project (not Django REST) and I have an API endpoint.

I have my payload structured as

```py
data = `{"cred":"averystrongpassword","books":"['book1','book2'...]", "prices":"['100','150',...]"}`
request.post("http://myapp.com/api/, data = data)
```

right now `books` and `prices` are a length of max, say, 30 each - but this might grow to thousands.

Is there a limit of byte-size a payload can contain (both from the sender i.e the `requests` module) and the API (Django) or does it all boil down to performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit, which is handled by the following settings variables

- [**`DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`** - (Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE)
- [**`FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`** - (Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE)

Also, if you are using ***Nginx***, you may need to look into the [**`client_max_body_size`** - (Doc)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) directive too.